# Android resource linking failed in android

Tags: android

This is the error I get after updating the IDE

> Android resource linking failed
>   I:\Android\AndriodStudioProjects\MedicalApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   I:\Android\AndriodStudioProjects\MedicalApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   I:\Android\AndriodStudioProjects\MedicalApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5353:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   I:\Android\AndriodStudioProjects\MedicalApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5354:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.

Comment: clean proaject and then Invalidate Cashes.

Comment: If not resolved your problem ,check classpath and gradle file and update it to latest .

Answer (score 2):

It seems your attr folder is damaged. Open the XML files inside the folder, check if everything ok

Secondly, if everything OK then try them one by one

- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild Project
- File -> Invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 1):

Please try

- Build -> Clean Project
- Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

Check your all layout .xml and you will get error. after solving error clean your code.

Build -> Clean Project

Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

I just found the source of the issue by using CTRL+SHIFT+F and looking for the problematic attributes in the code (of the entire scope). Turns out in my case the culprit was a third party dependency. Once i uninstalled it it was fixed. I guess the issue came from updating gradle and these outdated libraries somehow interfering with it.
I still dont understand the nature of the issue exactly but I hope this helps someone else dealing with the same issue. I just spent waaay to long looking at this.